# Does AMD have a webpage similar to ark.Intel.com?

Tags: cpu

I am considering buying an AMD CPU, but it seems that AMD is hiding their information. 
Maybe I missed it, but is there a webpage like this:
http://ark.Intel.com
or more specifically [Intel Core i5 680](http://ark.Intel.com/products/48504/Intel-Core-i5-680-Processor-%284M-Cache-3_60-GHz%29) where AMD CPU info is summarized?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Whats wrong with this:
http://products.amd.com/en-us/search

I don't see much marketing there, its similar to the 'ark' @ intel. Just gives you AMD CPU specs

Comment: Exactly, http://products.amd.com/pages/DesktopCPUDetail.aspx?id=773 looks almost identical to a similar Intel ark page, which I was linked to from the product listing page you (Jakub) gave.

Comment: The main problem I see is that it's a desktop CPU site. It doesn't have CPUs for laptops and smaller computers and no workstation/server CPUs either! Instead users must go to [here](http://products.amd.com/en-us/NotebookCPUResult.aspx) for laptop processors and workstation CPUs have separate site for each series and then again separate site for older models.

Comment: it's not as comperhansive as Intel's but it does part of the work. Such a shame that AMD is a company managed by amateurs.

Comment: The have different pages for different categories. Here's notebook processor page: http://products.amd.com/en-us/NotebookCPUResult.aspx. And this page lists all such pages: http://products.amd.com/en-us/

Comment: All the URLs in this answer can no longer be found and return a 404 - except for http://products.amd.com - but I too don't consider it a worthy equivalent of ark.intel.com :-\

Comment: Intel's ark is really another thing entirely. You can find the [datasheets for Pentium I processors](http://www.intel.com/content/dam/support/us/en/documents/processors/pentium/sb/24199710.pdf), from 20 years ago.

Answer (score 2):

If you're wanting to see actual benchmarks of these AMD processors VS the Intel processors then you can check out AnandTech.

http://www.anandtech.com/bench/Product/203?vs=288

[image]

Comment: Just a note, it's "AnandTech", not "AnAndTech". Anand is the guy's first name. Good site. :)

Comment: that's just comparisons, we are looking for complete tech specs to compare the AMD CPUs like the desktop Ryzen vs server Epyc not from a performance, but from a technical specs only perspective (ie. no pictures, only letters and numbers please)

Answer (score 1):

After a bit of reverse engeneering on the AMD-page I think you can go with this direct address: https://www.amd.com/en/products/specifications/processors